# Two operations with sed on the same pattern

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, filenames

I use this following `sed` command for display names of files with a specific form:

```
ls -1 *|sed 's/^\(.*\).png/\1\/\1,/g'
```

If I have two files named `BOH_Contour.png` and `BOV_Web.png`, I obtain

```
BOH_Contour/BOH_Contour,
BOV_Web/BOV_Web,
```

Now I want to remove all `_` in the second part of this result and to obtain

```
BOH_Contour/BOHContour,
BOV_Web/BOVWeb,
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's typically where you'd use the *hold* space:

```
ls | sed '
  /\.png$/!d; # discard everything but lines ending in .png
  s///;       # remove that .png
  h;          # store on the hold space
  s/_//g;     # remove underscores
  H;          # append (with a newline) to the hold space
  g;          # retrieve that hold space
  s|\n|/|;    # substitute the newline with a /
  s/$/,/;     # add that extra comma.'
```

Comment: Thank you. Your command works also on names with several underscores. With the comma at the end: `ls| sed '/\.png$/!d;s///;h;s/_//g;H;g;s|\n|/|;s/$/,/'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another expression to `sed` after `;`, eg:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\).png/\1\/\1,/g;s,/\(.*\)_,/\1,'
```

But keep in mind that [parsing `ls` command is not a good habit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: Thank you. Finally very easy... but too complicated for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Possible it helps:

```
ls -1 *|sed 's/^\(.*\).png/\1\/\1,/g ; : 1 ; s|_\([^/]*$\)|\1|; t 1'
```

Or if only 1 `_` in file name

```
ls -1 *|sed 's/^\(.*\).png/\1\/\1,/g ; s|_||2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If all names contain one underscore, then just match the two parts of the name separately. You probably don't want the replacement anywhere in the line, just at the end of the file name, so lose the `g` modifier.

```
ls | sed 's/^\(.*\)_\(.*\)\.png$/\1_\2\/\1\2,/'
```

By the way, `ls -1` is equivalent to `ls` when not used interactively. `ls *` is not equivalent to `ls`, the main difference being that if the current directory contains subdirectories then `ls` lists the entries in the current directory whereas `ls *` lists the entries that aren't subdirectories plus the content of all subdirectories. Given that this is hardly ever useful, you presumably meant `ls`.

If you want to remove all underscores no matter how many there are, while it's possible to use sed, it's rather clearer in awk.

```
ls | awk 'sub(/\.png$/, "") {$0 = $0 "/" gsub(/_/, "", $0) ","} 1'
```

Alternatively, you can use a shell loop.

```
for x in *; do
  case $x in
    *.png) x=${x%.png}; printf '%s/\n' "$x"; printf '%s,\n' "$x" | tr -d _;;
  esac
done
```